# No point upon uploading CSV in QGIS

Tags: plot, qgis

I'm using QGIS in mac, I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJ3ouh3EVVg) tutorial yet the points isn't visible in my layers. I'm using csv that is separated by semicolon. I assigned value successfully yet no effect. How can I plot coordinates using google roads. Attached is my settings. Thanks in advance.

[config 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9aPJ.png)
[config 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wPUT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comma, not a semi-colon, separates the fields in the "config" file.

In my installed QGIS version (3.3.0 Master) I was able to do this
-select a comma separated file
-indicate that the field delimiter is a comma
-indicate the "x" and "y" fields
-return to the custom delimiter area of the form and select a semi-colon

In my install, QGIS crashes.  I'd rather see an error message.

If instead, I select a comma as a delimiter, the point layer is created and shown.

Hope this helps.